# Appcelerator: "libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited"

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio, appcelerator-hyperloop

So I have third-party JAR and AAR files in my `platform/android` folder in my Appcelerator/Hyperloop project

When I tried to run my app, I encounter these errors:

`[ERROR] : /Users/myusername/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/TestApp/build/android/res/drawable-ldpi-v4/awsdk_beta_badge.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
...(same error for different png files)
[ERROR] :  /Users/myusername/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/TestApp/build/android/res/values/values.xml:817: error: Resource entry app_name is already defined.
[ERROR] :  /Users/myusername/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/TestApp/build/android/res/values/strings.xml:3: Originally defined here.`

I tried modifying the images using `ImageMagick` as suggested by in similar threads to this issue, but that doesn't seem to help because every time I click `Run` in Appcelerator Studio, the image files in the `build/android/res` folder are overridden (i.e. re-created and replaced) for each and every build. Is there a way to prevent these image files from being modified every time I click Run or is there any other way to resolve this issue?

I modified the png files via ImageMagick by changing current directories to the directories specified in the error messages and ran this command on each of those directories with the images: `mogrify *.png`

Comment: It might help to know what your exact ImageMagick command was. Also perhaps you can post your input image. Apparently libpng does not like something about the icc profile.

Comment: @fmw42 I used `mogrify *.png` on each of the image folders to supposedly clean the metadata of all the png files as suggested by high-rated answers on other threads However, it doesn't look like it matters since every time I run the app, the files in `build/android` are deleted and re-added.

Comment: mogrify will over-write your image unless you add the -path option to write to a different existing directory. To clean the files of all meta data, you need to add -strip. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify and http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#strip. Without adding -strip, you are just reading and writing the same file again with no change. If you just want to get rid of profiles, then use +profile "*". See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#profile

Comment: CONTINUED: Just to be clear -strip will remove profiles and all other meta data. +profile will only remove profiles.

Comment: The issue is that the 3rd party JAR or AAR file that it is coming from is automatically generating these images during compile time. So no matter what modifications I make to the build path, those images will be deleted and re-added by the library containing the image icons.